# Why would this db.eval -> array.push execute twice for certain records?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I wanted to add an object element to arrays in records matching a simple selector, so I ran this query:

```
db.eval(function() { 
    db.companies.find({exchange: 'OTC'}).forEach(function(c) {
          c.links.push({
            url: 'http://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/' + c.symbol + '/profile',
            text: 'OTCMarkets.com'
          });
          db.companies.save(c);
    });
});
```

Out of about 10,000 records that matched the selector, about 1100 ended up with *two* links pushed at the end of the array. What can possibly cause that? About 1000 had an empty `links` array, but ~100 others had one or more elements in the array:

```
{
"_id": "...",
...
"exchange": "OTC",
"links": [
    {
        "text": "Website",
        "url": "..."
    },
    {
        "text": "OTCMarkets.com",
        "url": "http://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/GREN/profile"
    },
    {
        "text": "OTCMarkets.com",
        "url": "http://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/GREN/profile"
    }
],
"name": "GreenSmart Corp.",
...
}
```

Most other records correctly got only one array element pushed:

```
{
"_id": "6WiXSoefPtqJdmzxa",
...
"exchange": "OTC",
...
"links": [
    {
        "text": "Website",
        "url": "..."
    },
    {
        "text": "Financial Information",
        "url": "..."
    },
    {
        "text": "Executives",
        "url": "..."
    },
    {
        "text": "OTCMarkets.com",
        "url": "http://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/SFEF/profile"
    }
],
"name": "Santa Fe Financial Corp.",
...
}
```

I have omitted fields from the record for brevity, but I can't fathom why some would get the OTCMarkets link element pushed once, while others twice.

Mongo 2.6.3.

Answer (score 2):

Because of your sort:

```
 db.companies.find({exchange: 'OTC'})
```

It is naural sort, and since your update is most likely not in place for those 1,100 it is causing some documens to move to the end of MongoDB internal linked lists, which is the default sort order; as such you are getting duplicate documents.

Sort your query with something like _id or whatever, just something.

Comment: How odd. And totally counter-intuitive, violating the principle of least surprise.

Comment: @DanDascalescu it is an odd one but that is what happens when you use contigeous space allocations for documents, when it out grows its space it has to move to a new one and that change needs to be recorded, and since there is no sort it is assumed you want to return in that order

Comment: Yeah but I hope it's not assumed that you want 10% of your records processed twice.

Comment: For what it's worth, this phenomenon is [clearly documented](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter) and there is an `$isolated` operator (documented at that link) that will prevent yielding during the update and should prevent seeing the same document twice. Be warned, however, that this means the update will hold a database-level lock (in 2.6) for its duration.

Comment: @wdberkeley does that have sharded isolation yet?

Comment: `$isolated` should percolate to all the shards and the problem occurs because of non-isolation of the update across documents within one mongod, so it should be fine in sharded environments.

Comment: @wdberkeley so the big fat warning is wrong: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/isolated/#up._S_isolated ?

Comment: No, most likely it's right but there's some more subtle issue I haven't thought of. I withdraw the previous comment.

Comment: Thinking about it more, I think the reason it's documented as not working in sharded clusters is that it doesn't provide complete isolation of the whole update from being seen until it is finished or errors, since different shards will finish the update at different times and so having `$isolated` really isolate the whole operation would involve coordination among shards. It should still protect against the OP's problem, I believe, but caveat emptor as it is documented not to work in sharded setups. Thanks for the nice followup question.

Comment: @wdberkeley I was going to edit my answer but I am still a little stuck on how this stops document moving and mongodb from reading those moved documents, does isloated go as far as to not update the on disk documents causing this movement in the first place?

Comment: The database-level lock on each shard while it runs its part of the update will stop the balancer from moving chunks. The process occurs via regular inserts/deletes, so it follows the same rules for locks. Maybe this would be good as a separate question? I feel the vengeful spirits of SO will sniff out a comment thread as long and tenuously pertinent to the question as this.

Comment: @wdberkeley indeed most likely, I am definitley interested in how isolated could stop reading moved documents

Comment: @wdberkeley http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190999/can-isolated-stop-reading-changed-documents-in-natural-order-in-a-multi-update over here

Answer (score 2):

You question got hijacked for a bit of a side discussion, but I wanted to fix my mistakes here in an answer so as not to mislead you or anyone else. The `$isolated` operator is not going to help you as it is your own update which is causing documents to move (because they change size) and then be rediscovered again with the collection scan. Use a sort as Sammaye suggests.

Also, please don't use `$isolated` unless you're really sure you need an isolated update; also don't forget that an `$isolated` update, while isolated, is not atomic.

Finally, please don't use db.eval. It has a bunch of limitations discussed in its [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/) and is meant to be replaced by the aggregation framework and doing > 1 call to the database.

Comment: What should be used instead of `db.eval` to iterate through all records and update each record based on fields within it?