# Can $isolated stop reading changed documents in natural order in a multi update?

Tags: mongodb

Following on from this question: [Why would this db.eval -> array.push execute twice for certain records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150795/why-would-this-db-eval-array-push-execute-twice-for-certain-records/25154814#25154814) I have a related question.

It has been stated that `$isolated`, in the comments, can actually stop MongoDB from reading moved documents caused by a multi-update.

My main point of contention is the alert on the `$isolated` page that states: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/isolated/#up._S_isolated

> The $isolated isolation operator does not provide “all-or-nothing” atomicity for write operations.

As such it doesn't first write to a static view in memory, `$isolated` is merely about stopping interweaving operations not to stop getting already updated documents (by the same operation) back in a multi-update call, a.k.a from what I can see it does not provide the atomicity and isolation required.

So how can `$isolated` work here to solve the related OPs problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$isolated` takes a write lock until the write completes or encounters an error, and it does not yield the lock while processing. This prevents other reads and writes. It does *not* provide all-or-nothing atomicity because, if an error occurs on the 32756th document, the previous 32755 updates will remain. There is no rollback; the update is not atomic. The update is isolated.

This will not help the OP, however, since it's his own update that is moving documents (via `$push`) and causing them to be hit twice. Use a sort on an indexed field; you always have `_id`.

Comment: Ah I am still confused, how is the different to running the update op with no other ops running at the same time? How can it ensure that at it reads in batches from the MongoDB data files it doesn't pick duplicate records on natural sort due to moved documents?

Comment: As far as I know the write lock will not stop documents moving right?

Comment: Hmm...you know I think you are right and I have confused the issue. I'll update the answer here and put (yet another) comment on the original answer.